# SQL Query for In/Out time attendance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a two table with the below sample output.
tb1 is in time and tb2 is out time
[image]

I want to build a query to achieve the below results with null values if row in tb2 not in tb2 or row in tb1 not in tb1:

i need get null if OINDX in table2 and not in table1 or IINDX in table1 and not in table2

[image]

this code to create two tables to try code and help me

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TIMEIN](
       [IINDX] [int] NULL,
       [USERID] [int] NULL,
       [Date] [date] NULL,
       [CHECKTIME] [datetime] NULL,
       [CHECKTYPE] [varchar](1) NULL
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (1, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-07' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-07T06:58:48.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (3, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-08' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-08T06:01:09.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (6, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-09' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-09T06:57:43.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (8, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-10' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-10T06:34:28.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (10, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-11' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-11T05:59:38.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (12, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-12' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-12T06:02:14.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (14, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-13' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-13T06:00:25.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (16, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-14' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-14T06:01:59.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (18, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-15' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-15T06:01:56.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (20, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-22' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-22T13:58:31.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (22, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-23' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-23T18:57:01.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (24, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-24' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-24T21:54:01.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (26, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-25' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-25T21:53:58.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (28, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-26' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-26T22:03:14.000' AS DateTime), N'I')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEIN]  VALUES (30, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-27' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-27T21:57:51.000' AS DateTime), N'I')

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TIMEOUT](
       [OINDX] [int] NULL,
       [USERID] [int] NULL,
       [Date] [date] NULL,
       [CHECKTIME] [datetime] NULL,
       [CHECKTYPE] [varchar](1) NULL
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (1, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-07' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-07T15:59:32.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (3, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-08' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-08T15:00:32.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (4, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-08' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-08T15:00:34.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (6, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-09' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-09T19:00:03.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (8, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-10' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-10T15:31:16.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (10, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-11' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-11T15:01:47.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (12, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-12' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-12T15:03:06.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (14, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-13' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-13T15:01:40.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (16, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-14' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-14T15:00:34.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (18, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-15' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-15T15:02:55.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (20, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-22' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-22T22:20:42.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (22, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-24' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-24T06:03:39.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (24, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-25' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-25T07:04:37.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (26, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-26' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-26T07:00:16.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (28, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-27' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-27T07:04:08.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (30, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-27' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-27T21:58:48.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
   INSERT [dbo].[TIMEOUT]  VALUES (31, 60, CAST(N'2018-02-28' AS Date), CAST(N'2018-02-28T07:00:18.000' AS DateTime), N'O')
```

Comment: Provide your table structures.  From your data it looks like it may exist in out but not in the in table?  Or can it not exist in one or the other?  (i.e. is one of the m required).  It would depend on how to write the query.  Also which sql-server version are you using?  You have 3 listed?

Comment: Full/right outer join - and, help out your users' eyes with those colors!

Comment: i need get null if OINDX in table2 and not in table1 or IINDX in table1 and not in table2

Comment: Weird.  Whatever is assigning the OINDX/IINDX numbers is already doing the hard part for you.

Comment: i update this Questions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428323/sql-query-for-in-out-time-attendance-with-null-row-when-date-not-in-table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[TIMEIN] i
FULL JOIN [dbo].[TIMEOUT] o ON i.IINDX = o.OINDX
ORDER BY oINDX


+-------+--------+------+------------+-------------------------+-------+--------+------+------------+-------------------------+---+
| IINDX | USERID | Date | CHECKTIME  |        CHECKTYPE        | OINDX | USERID | Date | CHECKTIME  |        CHECKTYPE        |   |
+-------+--------+------+------------+-------------------------+-------+--------+------+------------+-------------------------+---+
|       | 1      | 60   | 2018-02-07 | 2018-02-07 06:58:48.000 | I     |      1 |   60 | 2018-02-07 | 2018-02-07 15:59:32.000 | O |
|       | 3      | 60   | 2018-02-08 | 2018-02-08 06:01:09.000 | I     |      3 |   60 | 2018-02-08 | 2018-02-08 15:00:32.000 | O |
|       | NULL   | NULL | NULL       | NULL                    | NULL  |      4 |   60 | 2018-02-08 | 2018-02-08 15:00:34.000 | O |
|       | 6      | 60   | 2018-02-09 | 2018-02-09 06:57:43.000 | I     |      6 |   60 | 2018-02-09 | 2018-02-09 19:00:03.000 | O |
|       | 8      | 60   | 2018-02-10 | 2018-02-10 06:34:28.000 | I     |      8 |   60 | 2018-02-10 | 2018-02-10 15:31:16.000 | O |
|       | 10     | 60   | 2018-02-11 | 2018-02-11 05:59:38.000 | I     |     10 |   60 | 2018-02-11 | 2018-02-11 15:01:47.000 | O |
|       | 12     | 60   | 2018-02-12 | 2018-02-12 06:02:14.000 | I     |     12 |   60 | 2018-02-12 | 2018-02-12 15:03:06.000 | O |
|       | 14     | 60   | 2018-02-13 | 2018-02-13 06:00:25.000 | I     |     14 |   60 | 2018-02-13 | 2018-02-13 15:01:40.000 | O |
|       | 16     | 60   | 2018-02-14 | 2018-02-14 06:01:59.000 | I     |     16 |   60 | 2018-02-14 | 2018-02-14 15:00:34.000 | O |
|       | 18     | 60   | 2018-02-15 | 2018-02-15 06:01:56.000 | I     |     18 |   60 | 2018-02-15 | 2018-02-15 15:02:55.000 | O |
|       | 20     | 60   | 2018-02-22 | 2018-02-22 13:58:31.000 | I     |     20 |   60 | 2018-02-22 | 2018-02-22 22:20:42.000 | O |
|       | 22     | 60   | 2018-02-23 | 2018-02-23 18:57:01.000 | I     |     22 |   60 | 2018-02-24 | 2018-02-24 06:03:39.000 | O |
|       | 24     | 60   | 2018-02-24 | 2018-02-24 21:54:01.000 | I     |     24 |   60 | 2018-02-25 | 2018-02-25 07:04:37.000 | O |
|       | 26     | 60   | 2018-02-25 | 2018-02-25 21:53:58.000 | I     |     26 |   60 | 2018-02-26 | 2018-02-26 07:00:16.000 | O |
|       | 28     | 60   | 2018-02-26 | 2018-02-26 22:03:14.000 | I     |     28 |   60 | 2018-02-27 | 2018-02-27 07:04:08.000 | O |
|       | 30     | 60   | 2018-02-27 | 2018-02-27 21:57:51.000 | I     |     30 |   60 | 2018-02-27 | 2018-02-27 21:58:48.000 | O |
|       | NULL   | NULL | NULL       | NULL                    | NULL  |     31 |   60 | 2018-02-28 | 2018-02-28 07:00:18.000 | O |
+-------+--------+------+------------+-------------------------+-------+--------+------+------------+-------------------------+---+
```

Comment: Can i get this result without order by

Comment: You cannot get that result without order by Because null data will go  down . it is not the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

```
SELECT *
FROM TIMEIN t1
FULL JOIN TIMEOUT t2 ON t1.IINDX = t2.OINDX
```

Output

```
+--------+--------+------------+----------------------+-----------+-------+--------+------------+----------------------+-----------+
| IINDX  | USERID |    Date    |      CHECKTIME       | CHECKTYPE | OINDX | USERID |    Date    |      CHECKTIME       | CHECKTYPE |
+--------+--------+------------+----------------------+-----------+-------+--------+------------+----------------------+-----------+
| 1      | 60     | 2018-02-07 | 2018-02-07T06:58:48Z | I         |     1 |     60 | 2018-02-07 | 2018-02-07T15:59:32Z | O         |
| 3      | 60     | 2018-02-08 | 2018-02-08T06:01:09Z | I         |     3 |     60 | 2018-02-08 | 2018-02-08T15:00:32Z | O         |
| 6      | 60     | 2018-02-09 | 2018-02-09T06:57:43Z | I         |     6 |     60 | 2018-02-09 | 2018-02-09T19:00:03Z | O         |
| 8      | 60     | 2018-02-10 | 2018-02-10T06:34:28Z | I         |     8 |     60 | 2018-02-10 | 2018-02-10T15:31:16Z | O         |
| 10     | 60     | 2018-02-11 | 2018-02-11T05:59:38Z | I         |    10 |     60 | 2018-02-11 | 2018-02-11T15:01:47Z | O         |
| 12     | 60     | 2018-02-12 | 2018-02-12T06:02:14Z | I         |    12 |     60 | 2018-02-12 | 2018-02-12T15:03:06Z | O         |
| 14     | 60     | 2018-02-13 | 2018-02-13T06:00:25Z | I         |    14 |     60 | 2018-02-13 | 2018-02-13T15:01:40Z | O         |
| 16     | 60     | 2018-02-14 | 2018-02-14T06:01:59Z | I         |    16 |     60 | 2018-02-14 | 2018-02-14T15:00:34Z | O         |
| 18     | 60     | 2018-02-15 | 2018-02-15T06:01:56Z | I         |    18 |     60 | 2018-02-15 | 2018-02-15T15:02:55Z | O         |
| 20     | 60     | 2018-02-22 | 2018-02-22T13:58:31Z | I         |    20 |     60 | 2018-02-22 | 2018-02-22T22:20:42Z | O         |
| 22     | 60     | 2018-02-23 | 2018-02-23T18:57:01Z | I         |    22 |     60 | 2018-02-24 | 2018-02-24T06:03:39Z | O         |
| 24     | 60     | 2018-02-24 | 2018-02-24T21:54:01Z | I         |    24 |     60 | 2018-02-25 | 2018-02-25T07:04:37Z | O         |
| 26     | 60     | 2018-02-25 | 2018-02-25T21:53:58Z | I         |    26 |     60 | 2018-02-26 | 2018-02-26T07:00:16Z | O         |
| 28     | 60     | 2018-02-26 | 2018-02-26T22:03:14Z | I         |    28 |     60 | 2018-02-27 | 2018-02-27T07:04:08Z | O         |
| 30     | 60     | 2018-02-27 | 2018-02-27T21:57:51Z | I         |    30 |     60 | 2018-02-27 | 2018-02-27T21:58:48Z | O         |
| (null) | (null) | (null)     | (null)               | (null)    |     4 |     60 | 2018-02-08 | 2018-02-08T15:00:34Z | O         |
| (null) | (null) | (null)     | (null)               | (null)    |    31 |     60 | 2018-02-28 | 2018-02-28T07:00:18Z | O         |
+--------+--------+------------+----------------------+-----------+-------+--------+------------+----------------------+-----------+
```

SQL FIDDLE: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/26468/20/0

Comment: i need get null if OINDX in table2 and not in table1 or IINDX in table1 and not in table2

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided?  That's what a **FULL** join does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a "right outer join":

```
select t1.*, t2.*
  from table1 t1
  right outer join table2 t2 on t2.iindx = t1.iindx
```

Comment: i need get null if OINDX in table2 and not in table1 or IINDX in table1 and not in table2

Comment: Please amend your question, then.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you really want a `full join`:

```
select i.*, o.*  -- note duplicate column names
from ins i full join
     outs o
     on i.iindx = o.iindx and i.id = o.id;
```

Note this will allow you to get mismatches on either side.

Comment: i need get null if OINDX in table2 and not in table1 or IINDX in table1 and not in table2